# node.js puppeteer launch callback

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is there a way to use a callback for puppeteer.launch instead of wrapping it in an async IIFE?

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    ...
    browser.close()
})();
```

could be simplified to

```
puppeteer.launch(function(browser) {
    ...
    //browser automatically closes ideally
});
```

This has probably been answered somewhere but I couldn't find anything with a quick google search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work in that way, you could probably monkey-patch puppeteer:

```
const realLaunch = puppeteer.launch;
puppeteer.launch = async (callback) => {
  const browser = await realLaunch();
  callback(browser);
  browser.close();
}
```

But that's going to be confusing to contributors to your project that are used to the Puppeteer api as published in their documentation, so personally I wouldn't...